# Change property value background color for pseudo-element dinamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, pseudo-element

I have burger menu and need to change background-color by click on icon

I have this code in css

```
:root{
       --pseudo-backgroundcolor: yellow;
    }
    .menu__icon span,
    .menu__icon::before,
    .menu__icon::after{
        background: var(--pseudo-backgroundcolor);

    }
```

And this in js

```
const iconMenu = document.querySelector('.menu__icon');
const root = document.querySelector(":root");
let styleRoot = window.getComputedStyle(root)
let valueProp = styleRoot.getPropertyValue("--pseudo-backgroundcolor")
if (iconMenu) {
    const menuBody = document.querySelector('.menu__body');
    iconMenu.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        document.body.classList.toggle('_lock');
        iconMenu.classList.toggle('_active');
        menuBody.classList.toggle('_active');
        
        switch (valueProp) {
            case 'yellow':
                root.style.setProperty("--pseudo-backgroundcolor", 'white');
                break

            case 'white':
                root.style.setProperty("--pseudo-backgroundcolor", 'yellow');
        }
    })
}
```

or instead switch this

```
if (valueProp == 'white') {
    root.style.setProperty("--pseudo-backgroundcolor", 'yellow');
}
if (valueProp == 'yellow') {
    root.style.setProperty("--pseudo-backgroundcolor", 'white');
}
```

And i can't understand why switch or if/else constructions doesn't work. This function just doesn't see it.

Comment: you need to get the value inside the listener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is whitespace in the `valueProp`. You may want to `.trim()` this var before comparing.

```
let valueProp = styleRoot.getPropertyValue("--pseudo-backgroundcolor").trim()
```